# PHP flow logic problem

Tags: php, mysql

I have a bit of a problem with my PHP code, I am assigning values to variables in different states of the flow depending on what I receive, but for some reason it keeps getting stuck at one point, here is the code.

```
if (isset($session)) {  
    //if the user is in the database
    if ($row == 1) {

        $from = $_GET['from'];

            if (isset($from)) { 

                $page = $_GET['page'];

                switch ($page) {
                    case "game":

                        $page = "game";
                        sendVars($page);//send the variable

                        break;
                    case "gallery":

                        $page = "gallery";
                        sendVars($page);//send the variable

                        break;
                    case "leaderboard":

                        $page = "leaderboard";
                        sendVars($page);//send the Variable                     
                        break;

                }
        }else {             
                $page = "game";

                sendVars($page);//send the variable
            }

        //if the user is not in the database
        }else {

            //do this
        }

} else {

    //register
}
```

Now for some odd reason, it keeps setting the value of $page to game, even though I set the page variable to gallery like so http://www.mydomai.com/?from=set&page=gallery . the only reason for this that I can think of is that my switch is not working as it should? or it is bypassing the switch somehow?

Thanx in advance!

Comment: why are you re-assigning $page to game, gallery, etc. inside your switch statement?

Comment: have you tried putting in an echo just before your switch? I have found that to be most helpful.

Comment: @scunliffe I am re-assigning it because depending on what I get from the URL I need to send variables to a waiting flash file with the sendVars function.

Comment: @Kielie, you dont actually need to re-assign it as the case('game') acts like if($page == 'game'), so $page already is equal to game inside this case.  And the same for the other cases too.

Comment: @kielle You don't have to. If it gets to that case, it's already set to whatever value it's supposed to have.

Comment: @Kielie Did you get this fixed yet?

Comment: @Luke Well, for some reason it's still assigning itself to game.

The problem is that I am passing this to a flash game, so I need to check what I am getting from the URL and then according to the value I get from that I need to assign the appropriate value to $page and send that to flash, the problem is that the echo's I put into the switch statements seem to display accordingly, but the $page variable sent to flash seems to stay whatever I set it to in the else statement, any reason why it might be doing that?

Comment: I'll give it another go with your code though! Thanx so much for all the help! Really appreciate it!

Comment: @Kielie, could we see your sendVars function?  Luke

Comment: function sendVars($userID,$userName,$page){
 $returnVars = array();
 $returnVars["blank_one"] = "";
 $returnVars["userID"] = $userID;
 $returnVars["userName"] = $userName;
 $returnVars["page"] = $page;
  $returnVars["blank_two"] = ""; //send blank buffer variable to flash so it will parse XML correctly
 $returnString = http_build_query($returnVars);

Comment: Hmm if you are only sending $page to sendVars, but have 3 variables nessersary in the function call, you should be getting some warnings.  You need to call sendVars with sendVars($userID,$userName,$page) not just sendVars($page).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just ran your code after removing a few of the unessersary variable assignments:

```
<?php

// I added this function just for testing
function sendVars($page) {
  echo $page;
}

if (isset($_GET['from'])) {

  $page = $_GET['page'];

  switch ($page) {
    case "game":
      sendVars($page); //send the variable

      break;
    case "gallery":
      sendVars($page); //send the variable

      break;
    case "leaderboard":
      sendVars($page); //send the Variable
      break;
  }
} else {
  $page = "game";

  sendVars($page); //send the variable
}
```

And it all seems fine, xxx.php?from=1&page=gallery echos out "gallery", try doing a print_r($_GET) at the top of your script and see what it prints out and let us know.

On a side note I think the below may be shorter for you and still do the same thing:

```
if (isset($_GET['from'])) {
  // Check if $_GET['page'] exsists and is either game, gallery or leaderboard
  if (isset($_GET['page']) && in_array($_GET['page'], array('game', 'gallery', 'leaderboard')))
    sendVars($_GET['page']);
}
else
  sendVars('game');
```

I hope this helps

Cheers
Luke

Comment: I am getting Array ( [from] => set [page] => gallery ) with that same URL.

Comment: Thats good news, did you try replacing the code inside if($row == 1){} with the code above?  where exactly in the code did you print_r($_GET), from what I can see it should work if $_GET is populated as your above comment

Comment: So if you do echo $page; right above the switch it is "gallery"? If so can you add echo "test"; into the gallery case, see if that case is ever active.  If it echos out test then its all good, otherwise, is there any whitespace around gallery, struggling to see what else could be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing a var_dump($page);exit; before the switch and see what it spits out.

Also you can do a var_dump($from) and see what that is spitting out - it may be that it goes to the else, so it may not even be getting to the switch.

Comment: indeed - since the else block forces it to "game" I'd be suspicious that it doesn't even get into the switch.

Answer (score 1):

If this is inside a function, I personally prefer guard-style clauses than constantly increasing the levels of indentation. The idea is you pick out the bad conditions (ie if something is going wrong) to "protect" the larger block of logic.

In your case that's the switch statement.

```
if (!isset($session))
    return ...; // register

if ($row != 1)
    return ...; // do this

$from = $_GET['from'];
$page = $_GET['page'];

if (isset($from)) switch ($page) {
    case "game":
        $page = "game";
        break;

    case "gallery":
        $page = "gallery";
        break;

    case "leaderboard":
        $page = "leaderboard";                   
        break;
}

else $page = "game";

return sendVars($page);// don't need to repeat this if all cases do it!
```

It's just a style of code and it's not going to fix all (if any) of your problems. You actually don't need the switch block in there for this code. I can't see that it's doing anything.

Comment: If $page = 'foobar', you send it but it's not the case from kielie

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need the switch statement. I can't see an obvious problem with your logic but I think this will do the same thing:

> ```
> if (isset($session))
> {  
>     //if the user is in the database
>     if ($row == 1)
>     {
>         $page = (in_array($_GET['page'],array('game','gallery','leaderboard'))) ? $_GET['page'] : "game";
>         sendVars($page); //send the variable
>     }
>     else //if the user is not in the database
>     { 
>         //do this
>     }
> }
> else
> {
>     //register
> }
> ```

Just saw **Luke** used the same in_array method but 25 mins before me. Serves me right for being slow!

Comment: Using this method, you could do things such as read the "allowed" pages from a database or config file and populate the array that's passed into the conditional. That way you can add pages without having to change your code

Comment: That's great, will give it a try and report back, thanx for taking the time to help out!